React-Js State not updating in real time on a different page
I will try to keep it simple.
I have a list of todos which are displayed in a todo page.
I have a "number of todos" which are displayed on a home page.
I am trying to update in real time the "number of todos" when a user adds a new todos to the list.
My issue is that the state will not update until I refresh the "number of todos" home page. I want it to update in real time without the user having to refresh the page manually.
I am fairly new to react and not really sure what's going on.
This is the relevant code.
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [stats, setStats] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
    setStats(todos.length);
  }, [todos]);

  const addTodo = async (todo) => {
    const id = uuidv4();
    const datetime = format(new Date(), "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
    const newTodo = { id, todo, datetime };
    try {
      const response = await api.post("/todos", newTodo);
      const updatedTodos = [...todos, response.data];

      setTodos(updatedTodos);
      setStats(updatedTodos.length);
      setNewTodo(""); // reset the todo so it reset the input field as well
    } catch (err) {}
  };


<Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home stats={stats} />} /> .... 



import React from "react";

const Home = ({ stats }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="HomeTitle">HomePage</h2>
      <main className="Home">
        <p> Welcome to this website </p>
        <p>Number of Posts: {stats}</p>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;


If you are wanting to have them update in different browser tabs/windows then you will need to use a Websocket (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) (or similar) connected to a server to inform the home page that an update has happened

I suppose I got confused with the fact that react allows for real time update on a browser. This will need more work than simply using a state and passing it down to a component. Thanks for the insight.

React allows realtime updates within the same tab/window. If you have the same app open in two different tabs/windows then they are separate running instances of the code and are unable to communicate with each other

Thanks again for pointing this out, now I realize how unnecessary this question was haha.
